# Can android permission code and system service can be a part of viewmodel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am working on an application where I have to check permission and also I have to use system service.So where should it be added viewmodel or activity?

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = 
(KeyguardManager) 
app.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(app, 
Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Comment: is needs to make a system call, calling external activities, so this should go inside an activity